# JSON data output is ouputted instead of view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, controller

I have externally called a JSON Api. I have displayed the JSON on the page through the view but would like to output  stuff separately now so that it is good readable form because the whole array is all over the place. I want to make it look neat. 
So far:
 Controller:

```
 def index
   content = open("MY_URL").read
   @hash = JSON.parse content
   render @hash
 end
```

View:

```
<% @hash.each do |hash| %>
<%= hash %>
<% end %>
```

This is how the view on the page looks like (array):

```
["statement", {"generated"=>"2015-01-11", "due"=>"2015-01-25", "period"=>{"from"=>"2015-01-26", "to"=>"2015-02-25"}}] ["total", 136.03] ["package", {"subscriptions"=>[{"type"=>"tv", "name"=>"Variety with Movies", "cost"=>50.0}, {"type"=>"talk", "name"=>"Talk Anytime", "cost"=>5.0}, {"type"=>"broadband", "name"=>"Fibre Unlimited", "cost"=>16.4}], "total"=>71.4}] ["callCharges", {"calls"=>[{"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"07716393769", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}, {"called"=>"02074351359", "duration"=>"00:23:03", "cost"=>2.13}], "total"=>59.64}] ["Store", {"rentals"=>[{"title"=>"50 Shades of Grey", "cost"=>4.99}], "buyAndKeep"=>[{"title"=>"That's what she said", "cost"=>9.99}, {"title"=>"Broke back mountain", "cost"=>9.99}], "total"=>24.97}] [:prefixes, ["tasks", "application"]] [:template, "index"]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an hash to [`render`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) rails will to turn the hash into a string and ouput the string instead of rendering a view.

If you remove the `render` call:

```
def index
  content = open("MY_URL").read
  @hash = JSON.parse content
end
```

Rails will automatically try to find `app/views/:controller_name/index.html.erb`. It will pass instance variable `@hash` to the view.

In your view you are going to have to do more than:

```
<%= hash %>
```

This will simply call `hash.to_s` and the result will be like in your previous example. Rails is not a magic wand that will turn data into presentable html. How to do this is out of scope of a single Stackoverflow question.